# How set border without color value works?

Tags: css

Where does the border color come from?

```css
span {
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<span>CSS</span>
```

Comment: it takes black color as a default value

Comment: From the default, or `black` in most (if not all) browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes the [Default color of the element's color property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border).

> `<color>`: If not set, its
>   default value is the value of the element's color property (the text
>   color, not the background color).

In the below example, border takes red color, as the element's color is set to red.

```css
span {
  border: 1px solid;
  color : red;
}
```

```html
<span> Test </span>
```